# Is there any higher authority than Zordon over the Power Rangers (movie)?

Tags: power-rangers, power-rangers-2017

It's not explained in the movie, but maybe there is some information from the creators.

In the movie Zordon was the Red Ranger before Jason. So the question is:

- Who created the technology for the Rangers armor/zords/spaceship etc. (in the movie)?
- Who they actually answer to? The current Rangers apparently answer to Zordon himself, so was he always in charge with no oversight?

If no information from the movie creators exists, maybe some guess based on the original franchise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only answer that we can give, until the director/screenwriter answering in an interview or we get a sequel, is that we don't know.

What we do know is that there are other teams of Rangers.  Each Ranger team has a leader (as Zordon was, and Jason is) and similar resources (armor, weapons, Zords, presumably ships).  We know also that there are a significant number of agents who seek to capture or control Zeo Crystals (Rita was one such agent).

It isn't clear, however, if each Ranger team is created and acts independently or if there is a central command which organizes the Ranger teams.

It seems likely that Ranger teams operate mostly independently, without a higher authority to answer to or take direction from.  If such an authority existed - some group which created and managed Ranger teams - it would seem unreasonable for them to not make an attempt to retrieve Zordon's team's Power Coins, Zords, or ship.

Comment: We can also gather from Tommy Oliver's multiple appearances that there does seem to be at least some inter-team communication, or at least the awareness of other teams, at some point. That is, unless TO was simply recruited again (not sure of backstories past the original series). But if not, then we could assume Zordon knows of (and possibly works in some capacity with) the other leaders.

Comment: @SonOfSam - please note that this question was specific to the 2017 movie, not the series as a whole.  Tommy isn't even seen in the movie.

Comment: "If no information from the movie creators exists, maybe some guess based on the original franchise?" Does this not imply that the older stuff could be drawn from? I made a guess based on the OS. Exactly what the last line in the question said I could do.

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd: Yes, Tommy was recruited again. Each series takes place after the previous one ends.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks Are they all really chronologically ordered based on creation?

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd: While I haven't watched them in a while, I'm fairly certain they all take place chronologically. For instance, the end of *Turbo* saw the Rangers go into space, starting the series *Power Ranger In Space*. This is also what allows for the "group up" episodes where the past and present Rangers fight together. But in your instance of Tommy, in *MMPR* he was a teenager in high school, but in *Dino* he was a professor.